# Are there any tiny screen I could use to make a wearable RPi?

Tags: screen

I really want to make a wearable Raspberry Pi, but I need a screen. I found some video glasses, but they're awfully expensive and mostly in the US, which is a problem since I live in Germany. Are there any small screens I could make something with (like a HUD or some I could wear on my arm)?

PS: I'm not very experienced, so (disassemble-and)-plug-and-play-*ish* is better

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options. For simplicity, check into car rear-view monitors - they come as small as 3.5". Take a look at:
http://www.skpang.co.uk/blog/archives/541 for wiring/ideas for putting it together.
Also check out a 3.2" touch screen here:
http://www.recantha.co.uk/blog/?p=4246

Comment: Can they be battery powered?

Comment: Yes, providing you get the voltage right. Depending on the screen, you might get away with a 5V source even though the screen is supposed to be connected to 12V. Alternatively, a 12V source split between the screen and a voltage adapter connected to the Pi (to bring it down to 5V) would work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in Germany as well, and I'm just looking for a small monitor to use with a Raspberry PI, too.

The cheapest one I found [costs 21.50 Euros for a 3.5" device](http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B00C09LVAC/ref=noref?ie=UTF8&psc=1&s=automotive).
*(also available as 4.3", which costs 24.95 Euros).*

For a few euros more, there are models available by another supplier, also in [3.5"](http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B004VQD966/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?ie=UTF8&psc=1&smid=A2X2NO3429IQ5W) and [4.3"](http://www.amazon.de/TaoTronics%C2%AE-TT-CM05-modische-Digital-Monitor/dp/B0058S323Q/ref=pd_sim_auto_11).
Advantage of these model over the others: there are reviews by customers who got these monitors to work with a Raspberry PI - including the correct config values (for example [here](http://www.amazon.de/review/RD5K2GBU4ZPF/ref=cm_cr_dp_title?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B004VQD966&channel=detail-glance&nodeID=78191031&store=automotive) and [here](http://www.amazon.de/review/R2HLB8EDRBMNLJ/ref=cm_cr_dp_title?ie=UTF8&ASIN=B0058S323Q&channel=detail-glance&nodeID=340843031&store=computers) - *in German*)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=43286

Have a click on the above texy sells these as a add on board 1.5"